# Replace row when duplicate primarykey found

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, hibernate

I have a table where I wish to replace a row when duplicate Primary (unique) key is found.

```
Create table History (
  id varchar(5) not null,
  name varcah(30),
  primary key (id)
) engine=InnoDB character set utf8;
```

I'm using this with hibernate. id column is declared as `@Id @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)`

Help me change the above SQL, Hibernate annotations to allow REPLACE on duplicate primary key is found

Comment: Why don't you just call the Hibernate update method? That's specifically what it was designed for. `sessionFactory().getCurrentSession().update(object);`

Comment: saveOrUpdate is what I need

Comment: I thought so, your question made no sense on its own

Answer (score 1):

The database Primary Key is not meant to be ever updated/replaced. There are workarounds but those are bad-practices.

You'd better use AUTO INCREMENT(MySQL), IDENTITY(MSSQL) or SEQUENCE(ORACLE, PostgreSQL) ID generation.

If you use MANUAL ID assignment and you get duplicate primary key violations, you have to check your current application concurrency design. Is the manual id assignment not thread-safe?

A database sequence or an AUTO-INCREMENT ID will save you from getting duplicate primary key violations.